# How can I set "Everything" view mode default on YouTube

Tags: youtube

YouTube have added a so-called feature which will by default show "Highlights" from your subscriptions.  They also have a checkbox which lets you limit the homepage to "Show Uploads Only."  This data is saved in a cookie so that whenever you visit the YouTube homepage it will only show uploads.

The Highlights feature, does not use this, so whenever I go to the homepage I have to choose "Everything" from the dropdown menu.

**How can I make it permanently save this setting so that I don't have to do it manually?**

**Update:** It seems to save this for a session only.  It saves for a while but goes when browser is reset.

[image]

Comment: And the question is...

Comment: How can I make "Everything" the view mode without having to change it every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[YouTube Default Everything](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lglhfcembnpbdigiepeafgllldfaelpf) is a Google Chrome Extension that I just made. It does what you want.

> **This extension will default the YouTube subscriber list to Everything instead of the annoying Highlights.**
>
> Are you sick of YouTube auto defaulting to the "Highlights" selection?  You should have the freedom to set your own default options and now you can!  This simple extension will change the default YouTube subscriber feed from "Highlights" to "Everything".